# How do I preload css with Webpack and React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, preload

I am using react and Webpack 5. After running a lighthouse report, I found a few css files that need to be preloaded. How do I do this in Webpack?

```
webpack config:

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require( 'path' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
   context: __dirname,
   entry: './src/index.js',
   output: {
      path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'build' ),
      filename: '[name].js',
      publicPath: '/',
      chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js'
   },
   optimization: {
      chunkIds: "named",
      splitChunks: {
         chunks: 'all',
      },
   },
   devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
         },
         {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]']
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
               MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                'css-loader',
            ],
          },
        ]
   },
   plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve( __dirname, 'public/index.html' ),
        filename: 'index.html',
        favicon: 'public/favicon.ico',
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
         filename: '[name].css',
         chunkFilename: '[name]-[id].css',
      }),
      new CopyPlugin({
         patterns: [
           { from: './src/serviceWorker.js', to: './serviceWorker.js' },
           { from: './public/offline.html', to: './offline.html' },
           { from: './public/manifest.json', to: './manifest.json' },
         ],
       }),
   ]
};
```

I tried Magic Comments (as follows) but it did not preload the css.

```
import (
  /* webpackPrefetch: true */
  /* webpackPreload: true */
  './Article.css'
  );
```

And I tried PreloadWebpackPlugin, but I could only get it to preload **all** of the css files in the react project, or none at all.

Ideally, the solution would only include what is needed for the given page...

Any ideas moving forward would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why dont you preload with `link` tag?

Comment: Why dont you use a pre configured create react app or even better - https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup

Comment: @PunitMakwana I can put the link tag in the render of the individual react components and achieve this, however it seems "hacky" as this would be better suited as an import when using React... Worst case, I can use this, though I would prefer a webpack based solution.

Comment: @Kal This is an existing app so I am hoping to refrain from recreating the base.